Missing character in font LatinModernMath
I use org-mode to export Latex file and the corresponding pdf. However, I have received the following warning:Missing character: There is no (U+0020) in font LatinModernMath-Companion/OT! 
There are no numbers in the output pdf and I compile the the .tex file in Overleaf it can generate the right pdf.
Any advice is of great help.
This is the value of my org-latex-pdf-process:("latexmk -f -pdf -%latex -interaction=nonstopmode -output-directory=%o %f")

What is the value of org-latex-pdf-process? Please add it to your question.

This isn’t an emacs question. You’re running an external process and that process is generating an error message. You’d be better off asking somewhere that answers LaTeX questions specifically.

The value of org-latex-pdf-process is bog standard, so there is nothing that can be done from the Org mode side. It has something to do with your LaTeX setup, so I agree with @db48x: I would post the question to the TeXSE and add the .tex file that is produced during Org export (they won't care about the Org mode file).
